# Inequality $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|r_i^2-s_i^2|\leq\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|r_i-s_i|^2}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $r_i,s_i$ be complex numbers. Edit: Let $n\geq 2$ and $|r_i|,|s_i|\in[0,1]$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|r_i|^2=1$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|s_i|^2=1$.

> How do we prove $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n|r_i^2-s_i^2|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|r_i-s_i|^2}\text{ ?}$$

I know that $|r_i^2-s_i^2|=|r_i+s_i|\cdot|r_i-s_i|$
What else can we do?

Comment: This is not true for all complex numbers. Let $n = 1$, $r_1 = 2$, $s_1 = 1$ to see a counterexample.

Comment: @CyborgOctopus Thank you for noticing that! Would you know how to prove this for $n\geq 2$?

Comment: This is not true unless you impose some additional constraint on $r_i, s_i$. For a counterexample, pick $r_1=3, r_2=r_3=\ldots=r_n=s_1=\ldots=s_n=0$.

Comment: @timon92 You are right, thank you!

Comment: The edited version is still not true. If $n = 100$, $r_i = 1$ and $s_i = 0$ for all $i$, then the left hand side becomes $50$ while the right hand side is $10$. I'm not sure that any natural variation of this statement is true. It seems like the left hand side will actually be the larger one in many situations since there is no square root.

Comment: @CyborgOctopus I hope this is the final edit needed to make the statement true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the fact that $\sum |r_i^{2}-s_i^{2}| =\sum |r_i-s_i| |r_i+s_i| \leq \sqrt {\sum|r_i-s_i|^{2}} {\sqrt {\sum|r_i+s_i|^{2}}}$ and $|r_i+s_i|^{2} \leq 2|r_i|^{2} +2|s_i|^{2}$. [ The second factor is therefore less than or equal to $\sqrt {(2+2)}=2$].